# any other solution to replace visibility collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

hello everyone I have problem with IE10 and chrome..after expanding the table the IE10 will not collapse and for chrome it will leave blank space between it..its work in ie8, firefox. I already try display:none and display: table-row..but it only works in IE 10..

this is the javascript code

```
function loadSessionLogEvents(id) { 
        var visibility = $('eventTR' + id).style.visibility;
        if (visibility == 'collapse')
        {
            $('eventTR' + id).style.visibility = 'visible';
            var tURL = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/home/Folder.action?listSessionLogEvents=&sessionLogId=' + id;
            new Ajax.Updater($('detailTR' + id), tURL, { 
                method: 'get',
                evalScripts: 'hidden'
            });
        } else {
            $('eventTR' + id).style.visibility = 'collapse';
        }
    }
```

so the code after I change should be like this?

```
function loadSessionLogEvents(id) { 
        var visibility = $('#eventTR' + id).css('visibility');
        if (visibility == 'collapse')
        {
            $('eventTR' + id).css('visibility','');
            var tURL = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/home/Folder.action?listSessionLogEvents=&sessionLogId=' + id;
            new Ajax.Updater($('detailTR' + id), tURL, { 
                method: 'get',
                evalScripts: 'hidden'
            });
        } else {
            $('eventTR' + id).css('visibility','collapse');
        }
    }
```

this is the clickbutton function

href="#" onclick="javascript:loadSessionLogEvents('${file.session.id}')">

Comment: are you sure `var visibility = $('eventTR' + id).style.visibility` is working because there is no property called `style` for the jQuery wrapper object, it should be `var visibility = $('eventTR' + id).css('visibility')`

Comment: to set the value `$('eventTR' + id).css('visibility', 'collapse');` - also what is the selector `$('eventTR' + id)` it tries to fetch elements with tag name `'eventTR' + id`

Comment: so its mean i need to change the property and make a css for visibility??

Comment: <tr id="eventTR${file.session.id}" style="visibility:collapse;"> i found it in html tag

Comment: in that case it should be `var visibility = $('#eventTR' + id).css('visibility')` as you need to use id-selector

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments there are multiple problems here

1. You need to use [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) instead of [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) for `eventTR` and `detailTR` elements
2. There is no property called `style` for the jQuery wrapper object, you need to use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get and set css values

Try

```
function loadSessionLogEvents(id) { 
    var $tr = $('#eventTR' + id);
    var visibility = $tr.css('visibility')
    if (visibility == 'collapse') {
        $tr.css('visibility', 'visible')
        var tURL = '<%=request.getContextPath()%>/home/Folder.action?listSessionLogEvents=&sessionLogId=' + id;
        new Ajax.Updater($('#detailTR' + id), tURL, { 
            method: 'get',
            evalScripts: 'hidden'
        });
    } else {
        $tr.css('visibility', 'collapse')
    }
}
```

Comment: i already try ur code but its doesnt work..the table doesnt expand for all browser..im still new with this javascript n jquery